# Pivot table blank cells

Tags: pivot-table

I have a column in my pivot table that is showing the word "blank".

I don't want anything to show in the blank fields. If it is blank I want it blank I don't want words in the cell. How do I make it so the word "blank" doesn't show?

```
DMIC    Dec 31  Insurance   ELG Lewis   (blank) 400             200 200                                 
Energy Solutions    Dec 31  Nuclear Waste   MEF Long    ??? 5000    1000    1000    500                 500 500 500 500 500     
Morgan Stanley Banking  Nov 30  Banking Cahill  Bitton  (blank) 700 200 100                         200         200
```

Answer (score 0):

I use conditional formatting and set the font colour to white. Every time I do it I think there must be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the blank Data, but clicking on the dropdown menu on the field header. You will be able to click Select multiple items and remove the check in the (blank) box.

Answer (score -2):

Try this out

- Right Click in the Pivot TABLE
- PivotTable Options . . .
- Layout & Format tab.
- In the:-Format section there is a box called:-"For empty cells show:"
- Make sure the above box is blank.
- Click on: "OK"
- Afterward refresh and you should be ok

Hopefully it works out